# Android Upgrade "sms functionality"

Tags: android

It is possible to write android application, that wold add button to new message window, and that wold change text when I want?

To be more precise, when I write message  I want to my application on button click, or automatically,  change part of my text how I want. 
For example I writing "this is first sentence.this is second." and when I press button I want to get "This is first sentence. This is second."

Can maybe someone give suggestion for good tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to add this button to the messaging app or your own app?

Comment: To message. My main problem are that i use swype application for Serbian language. When i write text message phone use some characters that are not uni-code(for example ć,č,š ) in this situation sms are shorter (not 160 character) and instead of one sms,i send 3,4... I want to write app that wold change this character in c,s, etc... I was think to add button that wold on the end change letters..I try with sms settings but not work...

Comment: You can't add a button to another app, such as Android's Messaging app. However, you can send SMS from within your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a simple app that sends sms messages would be better... You should use andorids sms manager APIs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html